# KDE Plasma does not always load wallpaper on reboot

Tags: kde, desktop-background

Ubuntu 22.04 (the "studio" version, probably doesn't matter), running KDE Plasma

3 out of 4 times on reboot, Ubuntu loads my selected wallpaper, a simple .png image. That 4th time, however, it just loads the default wallpaper. How can I debug this? Thank you!

Comment: Was this a new install, or were you using an earlier Ubuntu Studio  Xfce version and *release-upgraded* to a KDE Plasma system? (*where wallpaper issue can occur; that was an unsupported upgrade for a reason*)

Comment: New install, good question, thank you! Additional possibly relevant: I'm running the PC headless, viewing via VNC.